# Windows 10 password field hidden on unlock screen

Tags: windows-10, passwords, login-screen

I have Windows 10, upgraded from Windows 7. I have a bug that I've found discussed elsewhere but yielding no satisfactory solution beyond the non-solution "Reinstall Windows". However, I narrowed down the circumstances under which the bug occurs, so maybe that will help shed some light.

After I've locked my screen (for example, using Windows key + L), I'll hit Ctrl-Alt-Delete to unlock. The unlock screen comes up with my name and a field for entering my password. (This computer is on a Windows domain and I'm logged in under a domain user account.) Normally, there's no problem. However, if I don't enter my password and complete the unlock before the screen saver returns, then I'm stuck. *Then*, when I hit Ctrl-Alt-Delete again, my name will appear but, this time, instead of the password field, the Windows 10 dots are circling underneath it, without end, until the screen saver comes on again.

At this point, the system reacts to no key presses of any kind. No controls are on the screen that I can click to get to any work-around. I have no choice but to shut down the computer, holding down the power button.

So now I try really hard to make sure that when I hit Ctrl-Alt-Delete from the locked screen, I finish unlocking before time is up. Even so, do any of you have any idea what could be preventing the password field from appearing in this scenario?

Comment: Is there a reason you need a screensaver? Disable it.

Comment: It's the office standard, group policy, I can't override it. Perhaps more clearly, the Microsoft scenic photo of the day is displayed for a while with the date and time superimposed on the lower left, and then the screen goes blank.